# Multiple list comparison

Tags: python

I am trying to compare the values in l2 and l7 if their value is the same it will return 1 otherwise 0 than same as l4 and l9. Finally I want to compare every value again in this out 1 and out2 list to return 1 if they are identical otherwise 0.

```
def difference(l1,l2,l3,l4):

    out1=[]
    out2=[]
    out3=[]
    for i in l1:
        if  not in l2:
            out1.append("0")
        if i in l2:
            out1.append("1")
    for a in l3:
        if a not in l3:
            out2.append("0")
        else:
            out2.append("1")
    for b in out1:
        if b not in out2:
            out3.append("0")
        else:
            out3.append("1")
    return out3



print(difference(L[2],L[7],L[4],L[9]))
```

But it only returns 1 even they are different. Could you help me? Thanks

Comment: It's not really clear what this function is supposed to do, but the use of `l3` instead of `l4` in `if a not in l3` seems to be a typo; `a not in l3` is, by definition, going to be false every time, because `a` is an element of `l3`.

Comment: Also, it seems each loop can be replaced by a single list comprehension. For example, `out1 = [str(bool(i in l2)) for i in l1]`.

Comment: If you want to do a lot of this, pandas has vectorized comparisons, so `l2.eq(l7)` will return a vector.

Answer (score 0):

Right now, the second loop iterates over l3 and checks each entry to verify it’s in l3, and the third loop checks the two out lists. The second loop should be comparing l3 to l2, and the third loop should be comparing l1 to l3. There should also be some additinal loops comparing l1, l2, and l3 to l4.

Also, a better way to do this might be to convert each list to a set and perform intersections.